# Where can I find out where trains are at the moment, with a map or otherwise?

Tags: trains, online-resources

I am looking for a website like flightradar24 but for trains, or I like to follow more precisely where my train is than the limited "next departures/arrivals" information that is readily available.  Where can I find such information?

Comment: On the "close as too broad votes": I agree that there is a list of answers to this question, but there are precedents for this and the list is finite, manageable, and maintainable.  So I think this question is useful and should be able to remain open.

Comment: When you say _my_ train, do you mean the one you are on?  If so, sit near a window with a GPS app.  :-)

Comment: @WGroleau The latter may not work.  In particular, it works poorly on electrified railway lines.  And I might mean "my train" before I have had the chance to get on it :)

Answer (score 22):

### Austria

[ÖBB Zugradar](http://oebb-live.hafas.de/bin/help.exe/en?tpl=livefahrplan&)

### Czech Republic

[GRAPP](http://provoz.szdc.cz/grappnv) Online map with all trains by Czech railway authority (SŽDC) Trains colored by delay. In details of train are scheduled and actual departures

[ČD](http://old.cd.cz/mapa/?_s_icmp=provozmapa&vrstvy=VP#)

### Denmark

[Landets Puls](http://www.dsb.dk/trafikinformation/folg-dit-tog-pa-et-kort/).

### Finland

[VR](https://junatkartalla.vr.fi/?lang=en-US)

### France

<strike>[Géolocalisation des trains | SNCF](http://www.sncf.com/fr/geolocalisation)</strike>
Location on a map is no longer available (since at least June 2022). One can usually see between which stations a train currently is on SNCF Connect (app, web…) but this information is often incorrect in case of delays.

[Carto Graou](https://carto.graou.info/)

### Germany

<strike>[Livemap](http://www.apps-bahn.de/bin/livemap/query-livemap.exe/dn?L=vs_livefahrplan&livemap=yes) via apps-bahn.de.</strike>

[ZugFinder](https://zugfinder.net)

### Hungary

[MÁV](http://vonatinfo.mav-start.hu/)

### India

[ndtv.com](https://www.ndtv.com/indian-railway/live-train-status) for all IR trains with NDTV

### Netherlands

[Actuele spoorkaart](http://spoorkaart.mwnn.nl/) (in Dutch)

### Poland

[PKP](https://portalpasazera.pl/en/Mapa)

### Slovakia

[ŽSR](http://mapa.zsr.sk/)

### Sweden

[SJ Traffic Info.](https://www2.sj.se/en/traffic-info/traffic-today.html/search/) Can show the route and current position of a single train specified through the search box. Live position information is not available for all trains.

### Switzerland

[vasile.ch for SBB](http://maps.vasile.ch/transit-sbb/)

[Zugverfolgung](https://www.zugverfolgung.com/) / [Geops](https://mobility.portal.geops.io/de/world.geops.transit?baselayer=world.geops.travic&layers=paerke,strassennamen,haltekanten,haltestellen,pois,world.geops.traviclive&x=1060704.05&y=6448987.56&z=11.73).  Although it appears to show locations for many countries, only a small subset of data are actually real-time.

### United Kingdom

[Realtimetrains](http://www.realtimetrains.co.uk/).  Detailed times but no map.

[Raildar](https://raildar.co.uk/). Very roughly geographic diagrammatic representation. Tries to reconstruct how trains move through junctions *between* the reporting points in the raw data from Network Rail, but often fails miserably so can be confusing to watch,

[Opentraintimes](http://www.opentraintimes.com/maps). More control-center style schematic presentation of the same data.

[Traintimes](https://traintimes.org.uk/map/tube/) offers live data of the London tube and via "More Information" in the upper right corner you can switch to London buses or National rail.

[Traksy](https://traksy.uk/live). Alternative presentation of the same data as Opentraintimes with an option to "track" a given train.

### USA

[TRAVIC](http://tracker.geops.ch).

[San Francisco Muni](http://www.nextmuni.com) (choose "show map" after selecting line and direction)

[San Francisco Muni](http://www.sfmunicentral.com/) (subway only)

[Transit](https://transitapp.com/) (app. Includes real-time location data for some urban and commuter services)

[Amtrak Track your Train](https://www.amtrak.com/track-your-train.html) (Amtrak only)

### World

[TRAVIC](http://tracker.geops.ch) shows trains in many European countries, Australia, New Zealand, Japan, Indonesia, Israel, Brasil, Chile, USA, Canada; note though that for most trains the location shown is only interpolated from the timetable data. You can recognize a train for which live data is available by having a colored ring around the black ring (of the same color as the inner circle).

Comment: @Newton TRAVIC is for transit in Bay Area only?  I remember seeing one for Amtrak trains but couldn't find it just now.

Comment: You can zoom in to other parts of the map too. You can see trains and transits on the east coast as well. The Amtrack tracker is https://www.amtrak.com/track-your-train.html but I have never used it.

Comment: Note that TRAVIC includes a bunch of data that's interpolated based on schedules (you have to click on the individual vehicles to see that). That shows a predicted location, but not an actual GPS tracked one. Depending on the agency's tendency to operate on-time service, it may or may not be meaningful.

Comment: @ZachLipton From looking around on TRAVIC a little bit, it seems the trains for which there is live data available have another colored ring around the black ring. While they say that they use live information wherever available, I only could find trains in France and the bay area for which they had any.